# How to publish to KDB Ticker Plant from Java effectively

Tags: java, kdb, ticker, q-lang, exxeleron-q

We have market data handlers which publish quotes to KDB Ticker Plant. We use exxeleron q java libary for this purpose. Unfortunately latency is quite high: hundreds milliseconds when we try to insert a batch of records. May you suggest some latency tips for KDB + Java binding, as we need to publish quite fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not enough information in this message to give a fully qualified response, but having done the same with Java+KDB it really comes down to eliminating the possibilities. This is common sense, really, nothing super technical.

- make sure you're inserting asynchronously
- Verify it's exxeleron q java that is causing the latency. I don't think there's 100's of millis overhead there.
- Verify the CPU that your tickerplant is on isn't overloaded. Consider re-nicing, core binding, etc
- Analyse your network latencies. Also, if you're using Linux, there's a few tcp tweaks you can try, e.g. TCP_QUICKACK
- As you're using Java, be smarter about garbage collection. It's highly configurable, although not directly controllable.
- if you find out the tickerplant is the source of latency, you could either recode it to not write to disk - or get a faster local disk.

There's so many more suggestions, but the question is a bit too ambiguous.

**EDIT**
Back in 2007, with old(ish) servers and a very old version of KDB+ we were managing an insertion rate of 90k rows per second using the vanilla `c.java`. That was after many rounds of the above points. I'm sure you can achieve way more now, it's a matter of finding where the bottlenecks are and fixing them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data publish to ticket plant are is batch, like wait for a little bit to insert say few rows of data in batch, but not insert row by row once any new records coming